# Script to copy line that contains specific text and copy on another txt file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

we nedd a script for Windows to copy entire line beginning specific word and paste on another txt file

source file:

```
< Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 00:12:13 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
Compare hash: 74d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df7771112436c89b2c9
< Connection: keep-alive


< Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 00:12:19 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
Compare hash: 52d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df4401112436c89b258
< Connection: keep-alive

< Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 00:12:20 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
Compare hash: 33d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df7661112436c89b277
< Connection: keep-alive
```

We need only extrat third line of each one and paste it into another text file, the result would be like this:

```
Compare hash: 74d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df7771112436c89b2c9
Compare hash: 52d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df4401112436c89b258
Compare hash: 33d05d5b127a8cd4b4781f1956b78df7661112436c89b277
```

Comment: This site will help with issues on a script, but is not a service to create them.

Comment: `findstr /C:"Compare hash" "source.txt" 1>output.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the lines that should not be copied contain a less than "<" sign, maybe that would do the job:

```
type "Original.txt" |find /v "<">>"New.txt"
```

Or if you want all the lines that contain "Compare hash":

```
type "Original.txt" |find /i "Compare hash">>"New.txt"
```

Comment: Excelent, work very fine: